# Verify that the name and password match(php)

Tags: php, json, passwords

There is a check of the correspondence of the name and password on `php`. The principle is as follows: if the name is in the file (storing names and passwords in the json file) whether the password in the file matches that which was entered.

```
$file = "../data/users.json";

$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

$users = array();

if(is_array($json_array)) {
    $users = $json_array;
}
if(isset($users[$name])) {
    if($users[$name]["pass"] !== $password ){
         http_response_code(400);
    }
} 
else {
    $users[] = array("name" => $name, "pass" => $password, "id" => $i);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
        $users[$key]["id"] = $i;
        $i++;
    } 

    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

And here it is written in the file

```
[
    {
        "name": "qwe",
        "pass": "qwe",
        "id": 0
    }
]
```

When I enter a name that already exists and the password that does not match it, the script writes it as a new pair.

```
[
    {
        "name": "qwe",
        "pass": "qwe",
        "id": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "qwe",
        "pass": "qweqwe",
        "id": 1
    }
]
```

As I understand, this is due to the fact that isset ($ users [$ name]) will always be a falsity, but I do not know how to fix it. How can I fix my name and password verification?

Comment: `$users [$name]` won't work because you don't have that key in the array.
What you can do is check all ocurrences in a loop and try to match the name with any of them. I think PHP has map or grep functions, which could be better than a loop (even tough it's basically the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Phiter is right. If you only need the code to works, simple insert the name as the index of the array:

```
$users[$name] = array("name" => $name, "pass" => $password, "id" => $i);
```

EDIT:

This is the full code:

```
$file = "../data/users.json";

$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

$users = array();

if(is_array($json_array)) {
    $users = $json_array;
}
if(isset($users[$name])) {
    if($users[$name]["pass"] !== $password ){
         http_response_code(400);
    }
} 
else {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
        $users[$key]["id"] = $i;
        $i++;
    }
    $users[$name] = array("name" => $name, "pass" => $password, "id" => $i);

    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

I've just move the `$users[$name] = array("name" => $name, "pass" => $password, "id" => $i);` to the line below foreach (you want to ADD, don't you?!?) and put the $name as index.

EDIT 2:

If you want to preserve the json structure, try this:

```
<?php
$file = "users.json";

$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

$users = array();

if(is_array($json_array)) {
    $users = $json_array;
}
$newUser = true;
foreach($users as $user) {
    if ($user["name"] == $name) {
        $newUser = false;
        if ($user["pass"] !== $password) {
            http_response_code(400);
        } else {
            // GOOD PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
var_dump($users);
var_dump(count($users));
if ($newUser) {
    $users[] = array("name" => $name, "pass" => $password, "id" => count($users) + 1);
}
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Comment: Like this? `if(isset($users[$name] = array("name" => $name, "pass" => $password, "id" => $i);)) {
 if($users[$name]["pass"] !== $password ){
  http_response_code(400);
 }
} `

Comment: Yes, but now it is object of objects. I need array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $file = "../data/users.json";

    $json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

    $users = array();

    if(is_array($json_array)) {
        $users = $json_array;
    }


    if(isset($users[0])) {
        if($users[0]["pass"] !== $password ){
             http_response_code(400);
        }
    } 
    else {
        $users[] = array("name" => $name, "pass" => $password, "id" => $i);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
            $users[$key]["id"] = $i;
            $i++;
        } 

        file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
```